# Multistate Modelling And comparison of cumulative hazard

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am puzzled by the multistate modelling that I am currently doing in R. I have understood how to study the impact of a covariable on a specific transition via subdivision hazard ration through Cox modeling, but I have trouble to compare two specific comparison of cumulative hazard.

I will explain with a simple example : Let's do a Multistate model with 3 states : A, B, C, in an "illness-death" modelling (so A can go to B or C, and B can go to C). I want to study the impact of the state B on the occurrence of the state C. So I want to compare the intensity of the transition A->C to the transition B->C. I have found no package, and only some article describing method with no implementation in R.

It's easy to have the plot of the cumulative hazard (or the hazard rate), with the confidence interval, but the specific test comparing the 2 curve, I have currently not found...

But I have the feeling that I am currently in the wrong path to search.

Comment: do you have any code or data to show?

Comment: I do not think the desire to have this done in R makes it suitable for SO, yet at least. There's apparently a lack of theoretic knowledge about what test should be used, hence a difficulty in searching. Suggesting transfer to CrossValidated.com

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I will post it on CV.com.